# What's the downside to using daily indexes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 10 indexes that I rotate on a weekly basis that can reach up to 100GB a piece with 10-20 million documents depending on the index. After I rotate I typically optimize, but this can take quite a while and I even bumped into an OOM issue with a particularly heavy index.

I thought about moving to daily indexes instead. This would speed up optimization and would allow me to archive/close indexes on a more granular level.

Is there any downside to using a daily over weekly rotation scheme? I know there are a lot of variables that might influence this, so if there isn't a straight answer, what are best practice with regards to index rotation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll utilize more RAM for daily indexes, if you keep the shard/replication count the same for a daily index as you currently have for weekly.  The more segements/shards/indexes, the more RAM your nodes will use.

Your optimize will likely be faster, true, and you can close on a daily level like you said.

Your queries should also be faster.

I'm in the other boat, I found this while researching what's been done re-indexing into weekly/monthly indexes after a set number of days.  I was keeping 45+ daily indexes open, each 300-700GB, and JVM was running ~80%.  I hope to take oldest days, 7 at a time, to convert to weekly, and lower ram usage, but still keep indexes open (then maybe to monthly, etc).